# Spark Scala: "cannot resolve symbol saveAsTextFile (reduceByKey)" - IntelliJ Idea

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I suppose some dependencies are not defined in build.sbt file.

I've added library dependencies in build.sbt file, but still I'm getting this error mentioned from title of this question. Try to search for solution on the google but couldn't find it

My spark scala source code (filterEventId100.scala) :

```
package com.projects.setTopBoxDataAnalysis

import java.lang.System._
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object filterEventId100 extends App {


  if (args.length < 2) {
    println("Usage: JavaWordCount <Input-File> <Output-file>")
    exit(1)
  }

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("FilterEvent100")
    .getOrCreate()

  val data = spark.read.textFile(args(0)).rdd


  val result = data.flatMap{line: String => line.split("\n")}
      .map{serverData =>
        val serverDataArray = serverData.replace("^", "::")split("::")
        val evenId = serverDataArray(2)
        if (evenId.equals("100")) {
          val serverId = serverDataArray(0)
          val timestempTo = serverDataArray(3)
          val timestempFrom = serverDataArray(6)
          val server = new Servers(serverId, timestempFrom, timestempTo)
          val res = (serverId, server.dateDiff(server.timestampFrom, server.timestampTo))
          res
        }


  }.reduceByKey{
    case(x: Long, y: Long) => if ((x, y) != null) {
         if (x > y) x else y
    }
  }

  result.saveAsTextFile(args(1))

  spark.stop


}

class Servers(val serverId: String, val timestampFrom: String, val timestampTo: String) {

  val DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"

  private def convertStringToDate(s: String): Date = {
    val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT)
    dateFormat.parse(s)
  }

  private def convertDateStringToLong(dateAsString: String): Long = {
    convertStringToDate(dateAsString).getTime
  }

  def dateDiff(tFrom: String, tTo: String): Long = {
    val dDiff = convertDateStringToLong(tTo) - tFrom.toLong
    dDiff
  }

}
```

---

My build.sbt file:

```
name := "SetTopProject"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.3" exclude ("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql_2.12" % "2.4.3" exclude ("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
  "org.apache.hadoop" %% "hadoop-common" % "3.2.0" exclude ("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql_2.12" % "2.4.3" exclude ("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive_2.12" % "2.4.3" exclude ("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-yarn_2.12" % "2.4.3" exclude ("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy")
)
```

I was expecting everything will be fine because

```
val spark = SparkSession
.builder
.appName("FilterEvent100")
.getOrCreate()
```

is defined well (without any compiler's errors) and I use spark value to define data value:

```
val data = spark.read.textFile(args(0)).rdd
```

which calls saveAsTextFile and reducedByKey functions:

```
val result = data.flatMap{line: String => line.split("\n")}...
}.reducedByKey {case(x: Long, y: Long) => if ((x, y) != null) {
     if (x > y) x else y
}
result.saveAsTextFile(args(1))
```

What I should to to remove compiler errors for `saveAsTextFile` and `reduceByKey` functions calls?

Comment: Just check the type of `result`. Because you have only `if` expression, it will give something like `RDD[Any]`, hence `reduceByKey` is not applicable. You should use `flatMap` / `collect` instead of `map`, or add `filter`.

Comment: what is the compiler error?

Comment: compile errors: 

1) cannot resolve symbol saveAsTextFile
 
2) cannot resolve symbol reduceByKey

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
 val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("FilterEvent100")
    .getOrCreate()

  val data = spark.read.textFile(args(0)).rdd
```

to

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FilterEvent100")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(sc.getConf).getOrCreate()

val data = sc.textfile(args(0))
```